# Rails: Getting access to index values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, rails-activerecord

I'm new to Ruby and Rails and trying to work this out. I am developing an app that allows users to create and store lists of books. The books table has many books stored as: title, author, genre. The ranks table contains the list of book ids assigned to that rank or list and is tied to a particular user. The user table stores user information: username, last name, first name, etc. I have several indexes defined but I don't know how to access them. Here is my schema file and the specific index that I'm trying to access is the books_index.

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151102002730) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "author"
    t.string   "genre"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "ranks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "books_id"
    t.string   "user_id"
  end

  add_index "ranks", ["books_id"], name: "books_index", using: :btree
  add_index "ranks", ["user_id"], name: "user_index", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password"
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "rank_id"
  end

  add_index "users", ["rank_id"], name: "ranks_index", using: :btree

end
```

I appreciate any help you can give me as I've been looking for answers but not getting very far.

**Edit:**
Thinking that my database structure is not what I think it is. What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

Books table contains:
id|title                          |author                      |genre
1 |Moby Dick                      |Melville                    |classic
29|War And Peace                  |Tolstoy                     |classic
57|Fahrenheit 451                 |Bradbury                    |scifi
84|1984                           |Orwell                      |scifi
96|Hamlet                         |Shakespeare                 |classic

Ranks table contains:
rank id |rank title                |books id                 |user id
1       |my classics               |1, 29, 96                |4
2       |j.t.'s scifi              |57, 84                   |17

My goal is to loop through the book id's associated with each rank and produce the list of books.

Comment: What do you mean you want to access the index?

Comment: You need the stats on index usage?

Comment: I want to be able to assign book_id's to the book_index and get the array of book id's back out of that index.

Comment: @Yury Lebedev - I'm not interested in the stats at the moment, just trying to store and retrieve.

Comment: SQL indexes are used by database engines to quickly find and retrieve data, they're not meant to be accessed directly for functionality. book_ids will be automatically added to the index whenever you create a new Rank record. And you can retrieve an array of all book_ids in the ranks table by running a query like `Rank.all.group(:book_id).map{ |r| r.book_id }`.

Comment: I think you should step back and read about how to code ActiveRecord associations.  My evidence is that you're storing a string of associated book_ids to a given rank.  You're going to need a bridge table, which is what I think you're referring to as the index.  Unless this is actaully a 1-many where a book can be associated to only 1 rank.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

Comment: @JoeEssey when you talk about a bridge table you really mean a join table that links rank ids to book ids?

Comment: @user3072765, that's correct.  book `has_many book_ranks` and rank `has_many book_ranks`, then rank `has_many books through book_ranks`